# do we need a different script other thatn angular.js for $http to work?

Tags: angularjs

I have this code

```
 eventsApp.factory('eventData', function($http, $q) {
    return {
        getEvent: function() {
            var deferred = $q.defer();

            $http({method: 'GET', url: '/data/event/1'}).
               success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                    deferred.resolve(data);
               }).
               error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                   deferred.reject(status);
               });
            return deferred.promise;
        }
    };
});
```

but i get error 404,

these are the scripts im using,

```
<script src='lib/jquery.min.js'></script>
    <script src='lib/angular/angular.js'></script>
<script src='lib/angular/angular-sanitize.js'></script>
<script src='lib/angular/angular-route.js'></script>
<script src='lib/underscore-1.4.4.min.js'></script>
<script src='lib/bootstrap.min.js'></script>
```

this is my controller

```
eventsApp.controller('EventController',
    function EventController($scope, eventData) {
        $scope.sortorder = 'name';
        eventData.getEvent().then(
            function(event) {$scope.event = event; },
            function(statusCode) { console.log(statusCode);}
        );

        $scope.upVoteSession = function(session) {
            session.upVoteCount++;
        };


        $scope.downVoteSession = function(session) {
            session.upVoteCount--;
        };
    }
);
```

just wondering if i need a different script to make the $http work ?im using the AngularJS v1.2.10

Comment: Have you checked if you have injected '$http' in your controller ?

Comment: yes i have, i have edit

Comment: does your url  works by direct access in the browser ?

Comment: kind of , it doesnt show what is in url-'/data/event/1' (1.json.)

Comment: Try injecting '$http' through the function parameters. get users : function ($http) { .....}

Comment: i have edit adding more detail

Comment: I can't see anything wrong with the $http call. I'd normally use something like $http.get('/data/event/1/').success(..), but it's pretty much the same as yours. I guess your $http works fine, as you are getting a response back. Since it's a 404, my bet would be on the address path.

Comment: well this is the path \BuiltInDirectives\data\event\1.json, im using localhost/BuiltInDirectives/index.hmtl

Comment: If you're getting a 404, then there is nothing wrong with the $http service. All it does is send the request and if you get a 404, the request was obviously sent. The issue must be that your url is off. Check your chrome console for the full url of the request being sent and I bet its incorrect

Comment: it gives me   .... GET http://localhost/BuiltInDirectives/data/event/dataevent 404 (Not Found) ..., all the changes i have made just dont work